# newly installed Fedora 34 (into a 128GB SSD) and I'm already running out space?

Tags: fedora

- I installed Fedora 34 workstation/gnome edition into a 128GB SSD (using auto-partition).
- I then installed a few apps and flatpaks and I'm already running out of space.
- Looking at "df -h", my root partition is only 16GB.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: First, don't post pictures. Copy and paste the text using code blocks. Second, the `/dev/mapper/fedora_fedora-root` that is mounted at `/` has only 16GB. The physical volume that's on `/dev/sda3/` isn't a part of any of the volume groups and is effectively unused.. To solve your issue, add it to the volume group that contains the `lv` mounted on `/` and add some of the space to `/dev/mapper/fedora_fedor-root`.

Comment: Please add output of `lvs`, `pvs` and `vgs` to your question. Also are you sure you installed Fedora Workstation? This looks like default Server partitioning where only 15 G `/` is created and rest of the disk space is left unused (also Workstation uses *btrfs* by default).

Comment: I am 100% sure as I was using gdm to login and then Firefox and gnome terminal and nautilus

Comment: I'll provide the other info later